# How to repeat sound in a loop? Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, qstring, qmediaplayer

i am struggling with playing sounds in my loop. I am getting user value and depending on the amount of input data exact sound is being repeated. Minimal example code:

```cpp
 auto sound = new QMediaPlayer();
 sound->setMedia(QUrl("path to sound.wav"));
 //(...) 
 QString input = getInputFromUser();
    for (const auto &character : text) {
        //depending of character play some sound:
        sound->play();
    }
```

If i provide for example "ffff" input, i hear sound only once instead of four times. Why? I suspect that while short sound is being played, whole QString is being iterated through.

So how can i force loop to wait for sound to end and then let it do next iteration?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you checking ```QMediaPlayer::State``` ?

Comment: Yes, i tried it like this: `if (sound->state() == StoppedState)` but it did nothing.

Comment: but you'll have to way until the previous sound has finished

Comment: Yeah, but how to do this?